# Search city or zip in Rails search field and open Google Maps in new tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a search field for "Find a park near you." The idea is that when someone enters in a zip code or city, a new tab will open and the user will be directed to Google Maps. In Google Maps you can search for "Parks near 35209" etc., and it will bring up a map with parks near that zip or city.

Is there a way for me to take user input, such a zip code or city, and have Google Maps open in a new tab and search "Parks near..."?

It doesn't necessarily have to be this clean and precise. I really just need a new tab to open to google maps and search around that area.

My search field looks like:

```
%input{ type: "text", placeholder: 'Search by zip code or city', class: 'park-search' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple string concatenation of the user input and google maps url ended up being the best solution.

```
var mapRedirect = function() {
    $('.map-button').on('click', function() {
        var input = document.getElementById('park-search').value;
        var googleLink = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/parks+near+" + input;
        window.open(googleLink);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

gem 'geocoder'

in you model

```
  attr_accessible :city_name, :latitude, :longitude
  geocoded_by :city_name
  after_validation :geocode

  private
  def city_name
    self.city.name
  end
```

in your view

```
<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@location.latitude}%2C#{@location.longitude}" %>

<h3>Nearby locations</h3>
<ul>
<% for location in @location.nearbys(10) %>
  <li><%= link_to location.address, location %> (<%= location.distance.round(2) %> miles)</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. If possible I really just want to be able to open a google map in another window. I'm not sure if this is possible though.